# What is known about this extension of the Erdös-Strauss-conjecture?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, egyptian-fractions

The Erdös-Strauss conjecture states that $$\frac{4}{n}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$$ has a solution in positive integers for every integer $n>1$.

> What is known about this extension : The equation $$\frac{k}{n}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$$ with $k=5,6$ or $7$ and any integer $n\ge 3$ has a solution in positive integers.

In the case $k=5$, I worked out that a counterexample is only possible, if $n$ is of the form $20l+1$ and in this case, the conjecure holds upto $n\le 2\cdot 10^6$. I neither found counterexamples for $k=6$ and $k=7$. $k=8$ is no more possible , since $\frac{8}{11}$ has not a representation of the desired form. What is known about this extension ? Any ideas or references ?

Comment: I think that this is the Generalization which states that for any $k\geq 4$ there is $n_k$ such that for all $n\geq n_k$ we have a solution for the $\frac{k}{n} = \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$ and there is a paper in Arxiv for the cases you mentioned which gives a better than $20l+1$, i think in the millions.

Comment: I had recently shown that: for $x,y,z>0$ we have: $$1=\frac 1{1+\log_x{yz}}+\frac 1{1+\log_y{zx}}+\frac 1{1+\log_z{xy}}$$ (which is a special case of a more general theorem, but the other cases aren't apparently relevant to the question). I'm not sure about external efforts, but I have tried this problem in the past actually and this is the closest "generalisation" I came up with.

Comment: See [this section of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture#Generalizations). From there you can check out the references [12], [16], [17] and their later citations.